# Get the latest updated row saved with Ebean in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am learning the Play Framework. I have created some Form and saved the corresponding object into my database with:

```
object.save();
```

I want to get the object that is just saved.
I checked the documentation and found out that save() doesn't have a return type.

So is there anyway I can get that object? (The id column of the object table is set to auto-increment, if that may help)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You hava that object yet! check:

```
...
object.save();
debug("ID of the new object is: " + object.id);
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. Didn't think about that when the row is inserted with save(), the object is updated at the same time.